# How do I write output in same place on the console?

Tags: python, console-output

I am new to python and am writing some scripts to automate downloading files from FTP servers, etc. I want to show the progress of the download, but I want it to stay in the same position, such as:

output:

> Downloading File FooFile.txt [47%]

I'm trying to avoid something like this:

```
     Downloading File FooFile.txt [47%]
     Downloading File FooFile.txt [48%]
     Downloading File FooFile.txt [49%]
```

How should I go about doing this?

---

**Duplicate**:  [How can I print over the current line in a command line application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465348/how-can-i-print-over-the-current-line-in-a-command-line-application/465360#465360)

Comment: you might be interested in this easy-to-use module, it's a text progress bar.  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Answer (score 295, accepted):

You can also use the carriage return:

```
sys.stdout.write("Download progress: %d%%   \r" % (progress) )
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Very common and simple solution.  Note: if your line is longer than the width of your terminal, this gets ugly.

Comment: I also had to add a call to sys.stdout.flush() so the cursor didn't bounce around

Comment: Is it possible to do this with multiple lines? Lets say I have three different downloads, and I want to show the progress of each one on its own line.

Comment: I like to put the `\r` at the beginning of the line, and add a `\x1b[K` to clear the previous text.

Comment: What if I have multiple lines? For example, multiple downloads happening at the same time. It doesn't seem to work when I just add newlines, it prints infinitely. I.e., `sys.stdout.write("Download progress: %d%%   \n\r" % (progress) )` doesnt work

Comment: It seems like the simplest solution for python 3 (as mentioned in answers below) is:


`print("sample text", end='\r", flush=True)`

Comment: @Cyrus that worked seamlessly. Just fix the quotes with `\r` :)

Answer (score 64):

## Python 2

I like the following:

```
print 'Downloading File FooFile.txt [%d%%]\r'%i,
```

Demo:

```
import time

for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print 'Downloading File FooFile.txt [%d%%]\r'%i,
```

## Python 3

```
print('Downloading File FooFile.txt [%d%%]\r'%i, end="")
```

Demo:

```
import time

for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print('Downloading File FooFile.txt [%d%%]\r'%i, end="")
```

## PyCharm Debugger Console with Python 3

```
# On PyCharm Debugger console, \r needs to come before the text.
# Otherwise, the text may not appear at all, or appear inconsistently.
# tested on PyCharm 2019.3, Python 3.6

import time

print('Start.')
for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(0.02)
    print('\rDownloading File FooFile.txt [%d%%]'%i, end="")
print('\nDone.')
```

Comment: use this for python 3+:
print('Downloading File FooFile.txt [%d%%]\r'%i, end="")

Comment: On PyCharm Debugger console, \r needs to come before the text. Otherwise, the text may not appear at all, or appear inconsistently. I added the version that works for me as an edit, because I couldn't write multi-line code in this answer. I put it on my gist so people can view it while the edit is awaiting approval: https://gist.github.com/yulkang/40168c7729a7a7b96d0116d8b1bc26df

Comment: "\r" at the end of the string works for me in the debugger console on PyCharm 2020.1 (PyCharm 2020.1.2 (Community Edition); Build #PC-201.7846.77, built on May 31, 2020).

Comment: What about 2 lines print ?

Comment: minor  detail it's possible to move the `\r` to the `end` parameter, like: `print('Downloading File FooFile.txt [%d%%]'%i, end='\r')`

Answer (score 29):

Use a terminal-handling library like the [curses module](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html):

> The curses module provides an interface to the curses library, the de-facto standard for portable advanced terminal handling.

Comment: Not available for Windows.

Comment: @Diego there's now a support library for curses module on Windows. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19851287/1426237

Answer (score 16):

Print the backspace character `\b` several times, and then overwrite the old number with the new number.

Comment: interesting, I hadn't thought of doing it that way.

Comment: I like this because it doesn't clear previous commands (if you have multiple stages you want to leave on the screen)

Comment: Using carriage return (e.g. `print 'Downloading.... \r'`) also doesn't clear previous data, but it prevents having to know how far back to back up.

Answer (score 16):

For Python 3xx:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.2) 
    print ("\r Loading... {}".format(i)+str(i), end="")
```

Answer (score 9):

```
#kinda like the one above but better :P

from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep

for i in range(101):
  str1="Downloading File FooFile.txt [{}%]".format(i)
  back="\b"*len(str1)
  print(str1, end="")
  sleep(0.1)
  print(back, end="")
```

Comment: Why is this better than the above (I'm a Python n00b, so please excuse my ignorance :-))?

Answer (score 4):

A neat solution that has been working for me is:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
for i in range(10**6):
    perc = float(i) / 10**6 * 100
    print(">>> Download is {}% complete      ".format(perc), end='\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
print("")
```

The `sys.stdout.flush` is important otherwise it gets really clunky and the `print("")` on for loop exit is also important.

**UPDATE**: As mentioned in the comments, `print` also has a `flush` argument. So the following will also work:

```
from __future__ import print_function
for i in range(10**6):
    perc = float(i) / 10**6 * 100
    print(">>> Download is {}% complete      ".format(perc), end='\r', flush=True)
print("")
```

Comment: In modern Python, you can supply an arg of `flush=True` to `print`, so there's no need for the extra `sys.stdout.flush()` call.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3 the function [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) can get many arguments.
the full signature of the function print is:
`print(args*, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`

when `sep` is the separator of the arguments from `args*`, `end` is how to end the printed line ('\n\ means a new line) file is to where print the output (stdout is the consul) and flush is if to clean the buffer.

#### Usage Example

```
import sys

a = 'A'
b = 0
c = [1, 2, 3]

print(a, b, c, 4, sep=' * ', end='\n' + ('-' * 21), file=sys.stdout, flush=True)
```

#### Output

```
A * 0 * [1, 2, 3] * 4
---------------------
```

In python there are many ways to format string and even a built in formatted string type.

## How to format string

1. the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20format#str.format) function. ([some examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=f%20string#format-examples))
2. Formatted String Literals or in the common name [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).
3. format using % ([more about this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting))

#### Examples

```
name = 'my_name'

>>> print('my name is: {}'.format(name))
my name is: my_name

# or
>>> print('my name is: {user_name}'.format(user_name=name))
my name is: my_name

# or
>>> print('my name is: {0}'.format(name))
my name is: my_name

# or using f-strings
>>> print(f'my name is: {name}')
my name is: my_name

# or formatting with %
>>> print('my name is: %s' % name)
my name is: my_name
```

Comment: First example has "sys.sdtout" gives a syntax error. Change to "sys.stdout".

Answer (score 0):

```
x="A Sting {}"
   for i in range(0,1000000):
y=list(x.format(i))
print(x.format(i),end="")

for j in range(0,len(y)):
    print("\b",end="")
```