# Curses library in python

Tags: python

I have C code which draws a vertical & a horizontal line in the center of screen as below:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#define HLINE for(i=0;i<79;i++)\
                  printf("%c",196);
#define VLINE(X,Y) {\
                     gotoxy(X,Y);\
                     printf("%c",179);\
                   }
int main()
{
  int i,j;
  clrscr();
  gotoxy(1,12);
  HLINE
  for(y=1;y<25;y++)
      VLINE(39,y)
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to convert it literally in python version 2.7.6:

```py
import curses
def HLINE():
    for i in range(0,79):
        print "%c" % 45
def VLINE(X,Y):
    curses.setsyx(Y,X)
    print "%c" % 124
curses.setsyx(12,1)
HLINE()
for y in range(1,25):
    VLINE(39,y)
```

My questions:

1.Do we have to change the position of x and y in setsyx function i.e, gotoxy(1,12) is setsyx(12,1) ?

2.Curses module is only available for unix not for windows?If yes, then what about windows(python 2.7.6)?

3.Why character value of 179 and 196 are � in python but in C, it is | and - respectively?

4.Above code in python is literally right or it needs some improvement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779486/curses-alternative-for-windows/14779649#14779649 There's a windows port available for curses now. Not sure how stable it is but you'll find it here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you will have to change the argument positions. `setsyx(y, x)` and `gotoxy(x, y)`
2. There are Windows libraries made available. I find most useful binaries here: [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses)
3. This most likely has to do with unicode formatting. What you could try to do is add the following line to the top of your python file (after the `#!/usr/bin/python` line) as this forces python to work with utf-8 encoding in String objects:

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   ```
4. Your Python code to me looks acceptable enough, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Duplicate of [Curses alternative for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14779486/3168666)
3. Presumably you are using Python 2.x, thus your characters are bytes and therefore encoding-dependent. The meaning of a particular numeric value is determined by the encoding used. Most likely you are using utf8 on Linux and something non-utf8 in your Windows program, so you cannot compare the values. In curses you should use `curses.ACS_HLINE` and `curses.ACS_VLINE`.
4. You cannot mix `print` and `curses` functions, it will mess up the display. Use `curses.addch` or variants instead.