# import curses doesn't work in visual studio 2017 python

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have this project in Visual Studio, but when I try to import curses, even though it autocompletes it, there is a error that says curses doesn't exist.
Do any of you know how to fix that glitch in visual studio?

Comment: The message I get is that `import _curses` in the `curses` module fails because `_curses` (the C-library, note underscore) does not exist.  `curses` completes because it exists, even if it will not run.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using windows, right? `Curses` is linux library, you won't be able to import it directly. There are alternatives. More info on alternatives you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779486/curses-alternative-for-windows)