# Is there a way to directly manipulate the console screen buffer on windows from python?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, buffer, command-prompt

I want to directly manipulate not stdout, but rather the command prompt screen buffer itself with python.
I want to do this so that I can write over already existing info to create a sort of screen with the command prompt.
I'm assuming that this is possible with the win32api, but I can't get that working for some reason (probably territory for a different question).
How would this be possible in python?

Comment: You want something like curses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library) ? Some information about making it work for Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779486/curses-alternative-for-windows

Comment: I downloaded the `curses-2.2.1+utf8-cp39-cp39-win32.whl` file assuming that `cp39` would mean python3.9 (my default python install) but I got a `ERROR: curses-2.2.1+utf8-cp39-cp39-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` when installing.

Comment: you probably need a win64 whl ... I would recommend `asciimatics` its pure python so easy to install and it works on windows...