# Clear, update and save the current line

Tags: python, loops, printing, newline

How can I clear/save the current line in Python? I have a double loop that I would like to print the results of the inner loop on-line and save and show the final result of this loop after it goes to the outer loop each time. I have:

```
import os
for j in xrange(1,final_step_j):
    Result=0
        for k in xrange(1,final_step_k):
         Result=Result+ j*k
         os.system('clear')
         print "current Result for j=%s and k=%s is %s" %(j, k, Result)
```

Which `os.system('clear')` clearly clear the whole page every time it runs the inner loop. I want to save and show the final result of the inner loop each time and go to a new line for showing the result of the next round while the previous last line is still visible on the screen.

Comment: You can save lines in list and print all again after clear screen.

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect, but you could try writing a carriage return `\r` without a new line via the lower level `stdout` method:

```
import os
import sys

for j in xrange(1,final_step_j):
  Result=0
  for k in xrange(1,final_step_k):
    Result=Result+ j*k
    # Move back to beginning and print over
    sys.stdout.write("\rcurrent Result for j=%s and k=%s is %s" %(j, k, Result)) 
    sys.stdout.flush() # Flush without a new line
  print # Move to next line
```

The problem is if the line you're printing is shorter than the one you've already printed in which case you need to have more padding or make sure you have a constant amount of padding.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517127/how-do-i-write-output-in-same-place-on-the-console).