# python ftplib How to get the download speed? and upload speed?

Tags: python, performance, ftplib

If I use ftplib, How to get the download speed ? and upload speed ?
I don't know how to get the speed.
Thank u.

Comment: get the number of speed.

Comment: Perhaps progess indicator is what you need see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998013/python-ftplib-show-ftp-upload-progress

Comment: but..What can I do with python 2.7.5 ?

Comment: Yes there is a comment that shows a modification for Python 2.x.x

Comment: ok, thx......................