# Change string after it has been printed

Tags: python

If I have a line that says the following:

```
3 guesses left
```

After the print statement for this I have a loop that allows the user to input something and remove one from guesses each time e.g.

```
guesses = 3

while guesses > 0:
    guess = input("Have a guess: ")
    guesses -= 1
```

After the last line of code how can I make it continue to iterate through the while loop but instead of printing extra lines that say `2 guesses left`, `1 guess left`, `0 guess left`, simply change the number in the first line?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517127/how-do-i-write-output-in-same-place-on-the-console

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sys.stdout.write` with  `\r`. `\r` puts back to start of line:

demo:

```
>>> guess = 3
>>> while guess != 0:
...     sys.stdout.write("\rguess left " + str(guess-1))
...     sys.stdout.flush()
...     time.sleep(2)
...     guess = guess -1
```

or you can clear whole screen before next print:

```
print "\033c"        # python 2x
print("\033c")       # python 3x
```

you can also use unix and windows command:

```
import os
os.system('clear')  # unix
os.system('cls')    # windows
```