# show downloading progress in console

Tags: python

```
for url in addresses:
    file_name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    fname_with_path = os.path.join(download_directory, file_name)


    attempts = 1
    while attempts < 5:
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fname_with_path)
            print("%-3s %-60s %25s" % ('--', file_name, 'downloaded'), end='')
            break
        except:
            attempts += 1
            if attempts > 1 and attempts < 5:
                print('tried to download   ', file_name, '   attempt:', attempts)
            if attempts == 5:
                print("%-3s %-60s %25s" % ('--', file_name, 'FAILED'), end='')
            pass
```

Here's a part of code for downloading files from a list of urls. Since some files are big enough I'd like to know many KBs of a file are alredy downloaded. For example

```
file1: 348 / 2980
```

Also I'd like to update the progress on the same line, not like this:

```
file1: 348 / 2980
file1: 355 / 2980
file1: 389 / 2980
file1: 402 / 2980
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print out a carriage return (\r) to overwrite previous printout:
See also:
[How do I write output in same place on the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517127/how-do-i-write-output-in-same-place-on-the-console)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can print onto the same line in python 3:

```
print('text\r', end='', flush=True)
```

The `\r` is a carriage return and moves the cursor back to the start of the line

Answer (score 0):

I do know how it does in c/c++ languages. Just put `\r` at beginning of the line you want to stay on the same place and remove `\n` at the end.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/urllib/request.py#L283

In your case seems the `urlretrieve` uses `reporthook(blocknum, bs, size)` where you can override the report code as you wish, for example, like i said above.