# How to reset cursor to the beginning of the same line in Python

Tags: python

Most of questions related to this topics here in SO is as follows:

> How to print some information on the same line without introducing a
>   new line

[Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524) [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386).

Instead, my question is as follows:

I expect to see the following effect,

```
>> You have finished 10%
```

where the `10` keep increasing in the same time. I know how to do this in C++ but cannot
find a good solution in python.

Comment: Can you output ASCII character 8 (a backspace) to delete the 10, then write out a new value?

Comment: Nice.  Not sure that you need the `'\r'` at the beginning? 

This also works in Python 2, and may facilitate easier mapping from 2 to 3 in future:

`print '>> You have finished %d%%' % i, '\r',`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
import sys, time

for i in xrange(0, 101, 10):
  print '\r>> You have finished %d%%' % i,
  sys.stdout.flush()
  time.sleep(2)
print
```

The `\r` is the carriage return. You need the comma at the end of the `print` statement to avoid automatic newline. Finally `sys.stdout.flush()` is needed to flush the buffer out to stdout.

For Python 3, you can use:

```
print("\r>> You have finished {}%".format(i), end='')
```

Comment: And now, in "more-modern" Python 3:      print (f"\r>> You have finished {i}%", end='', flush=True)

Answer (score 37):

### Python 3

You can use keyword arguments to `print`:

`print('string', end='\r', flush=True)`

- `end='\r'` replaces the default end-of-line behavior with `'\r'`
- `flush=True` flushes the buffer, making the printed text appear immediately.

---

### Python 2

In 2.6+ you can use [`from __future__ import print_function`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32032727) at the start of the script to enable Python 3 behavior. Or use the old way:

Python's `print` puts a newline after each command, unless you suppress it with a trailing comma. So, the print command is:

```
print 'You have finished {0}%\r'.format(percentage),
```

Note the comma at the end.

Unfortunately, Python only sends the output to the terminal after a complete line. The above is not a complete line, so you need to `flush` it manually:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: is there a solution that is compatible for both python 2 and 3? The python 2 version but with enclosing ( ) for python 3 prints a new line  on the latter version.

Comment: @fjleon, yes! Use a `__future__` import. I edited the answer to make it a bit more modern :)

Comment: I actually found a solution that doesn't require the future import and posted it way below

Answer (score 6):

On linux( and probably on windows) you can use [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) module like this

```
import time
import curses

win = curses.initscr()
for i in range(100):
    win.clear()
    win.addstr("You have finished %d%%"%i)
    win.refresh()
    time.sleep(.1)
curses.endwin()
```

Benfit with curses as apposed to other simpler technique is that, you can draw on terminal like a graphics program, because curses provides moving to any x,y position e.g. below is a simple script which updates four views

```
import time
import curses

curses.initscr()

rows = 10
cols= 30
winlist = []
for r in range(2):
    for c in range(2):
        win = curses.newwin(rows, cols, r*rows, c*cols)
        win.clear()
        win.border()
        winlist.append(win)

for i in range(100):
    for win in winlist:
        win.addstr(5,5,"You have finished - %d%%"%i)
        win.refresh()
    time.sleep(.05)
curses.endwin()
```

Comment: link is dead :(

Answer (score 2):

I had to combine a few answers above to make it work on Python 3.7 / Windows 10. The example runs on Spyder's console:

```
import sys, time

for i in range(0, 101, 5):
  print("\r>> You have finished {}%".format(i), end='')
  sys.stdout.flush()
  time.sleep(.2)
```

The `time.sleep(.2)` is just used to simulates some time-consuming code.

Answer (score 1):

using `sys.stdout.write()` instead of print works in both python 2 and 3 without any compromises.

Comment: as an example, `sys.stdout.write("\rloading... %s%%" % percentage)`

Answer (score 1):

The OP didn't specify Py2 or Py3.  In Python 3 the 'import' of 'sys' and the 'sys.stdout' call can be replaced with 'flush=True':

```
import time
for i in range(0,101,25):
  print("\r>>TESTING - {:0>3d}%".format(i), end='', flush=True)
  time.sleep(.5)
print()
```

Thanks to **Petr Viktorin** for showing the "flush" parameter for Python 3 print().  I submit this because his Python 3 example doesn't include a 'format' specifier.  It took me awhile to figure out that the additional parameters go **after** the 'format' specifier parentheses as shown in my example.  I just picked an example format of 3 character integer 0 filled on the left.  The best doc I found for Py3 format is: [6.1.3.1. Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#grammar-token-sign)