# Problems with __future__ and swagger_client in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, swagger, python-import, strava

The Strava API documentation gives the following sample code which I copied and entered my own access token and club ID:

```
from __future__ import print_statement
import time
import swagger_client
from swagger_client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

# Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization: strava_oauth
swagger_client.configuration.access_token = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'

# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = swagger_client.ClubsApi()
id = MY_CLUB_ID # Integer | The identifier of the club.
page = 56 # Integer | Page number. (optional)
perPage = 56 # Integer | Number of items per page. Defaults to 30.     (optional) (default to 30)

try:
    # List Club Activities
    api_response = api_instance.getClubActivitiesById(id, page=page, perPage=perPage)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling ClubsApi->getClubActivitiesById: %s\n" % e)
```

I try to run it I get

```
from __future__ import print_statement
SyntaxError: future feature print_statement is not defined
```

I can also see that I will get the same with my `swagger_client` imports. I've tried installing packages for each but this hasn't made any difference. I read that for the `__future__` I should be on > Python 2.7 but I'm currently using 3.6.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Good question. To be honest I'm not completely sure what it is but I guess it contains packages which are not in the current Python version but which will be in a future version. I'm not a Python developer and am only seeing this for the first time so that may net even be an accurate explanation.

Comment: You don't need `from __future__ ...` in Python 3. See [how to use from \_\_future\_\_ import print\_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032697/how-to-use-from-future-import-print-function)

Comment: Even if I comment that out I get

`import swagger_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swagger_client'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) The first line contains a typo

```python
from __future__ import print_statement
                             ^^^
```

it should be

```python
from __future__ import print_function
```

But since you are using Python 3, you don't actually need this import - see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32032697/113116) for details.

2) `swagger_client` is probably the Python client generated from the [Strava OpenAPI definition](https://developers.strava.com/swagger/swagger.json). It looks like you need to generate it manually using Swagger Codegen. There are several ways to do this:

- Paste the Strava OpenAPI definition into https://editor.swagger.io and select **Generate Client > Python**.
- Install the [command-line version](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#prerequisites) of [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) and run:

  ```
  # Windows
  java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-<ver>.jar generate -i https://developers.strava.com/swagger/swagger.json -l python -o ./StravaPythonClient

  # Mac
  swagger-codegen generate -i https://developers.strava.com/swagger/swagger.json -l python -o ./StravaPythonClient
  ```

Comment: As a side note. The feature is named `print_function` and not `print_statement`. You are still able to import `print_function` in python3.x

Comment: @MegaIng Thanks. Looks like `import print_statement` was a typo in examples generated by Codegen - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5692.

Comment: OK, so I followed the directions above as best I could. Ended up with a folder called SwaggerPythonClient which contained a swagger_client folder containing configuration.py and rest.py so I copied the contents to my program directory. The import errors have now vanished but now I'm finding other issues. I can investigate and maybe post in a new question if required but want to check if what I did is correct before I continue.

Comment: For my above, I ended up installing several missing packages. My application now works.

Comment: I'm struggling with getting started too... would you care to explain which missing packages you also installed?