# How to install swagger_client in a django project

Tags: python-3.x, swagger, strava

I am facing with the problem of **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swagger_client'** when trying to run the below code.

How it is possible to import swagger_client?

I want to have access to a custom api.

my code :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import swagger_client
from swagger_client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint


# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = swagger_client.BookingApi()
reservationId =  # Long | reservation id

try: 
    # Cancel reservation
    api_response = api_instance.cancel_reservation(reservationId)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling BookingApi->cancelReservation: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swagger_client in python trying to use Strava API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55657275/113116)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you've installed the correct package? I ran `pip3 install swagger_client` and `pip3 install swaggerclient` and it it told me that there was no matching distribution.

[Here is a link](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) to what appears to be a the most popular Python swagger implementation for Django, along with a good quick start guide that looks similar to what you are trying to accomplish.

Otherwise, [this list](https://swagger.io/tools/open-source/open-source-integrations/) contains all community-driven integrations of Swagger in their respective languages. Lots of different ones to choose from when working with Python.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is still relevant, but what worked for me to set up swagger_ client is that after I downloaded the specific client for the API I want to use, i.e., once I got the **python-client-generated.zip** from the swagger editor, I **extracted** it and then run the **python setup.py install** in the same folder I extracted it to. Then I just picked the folders called **swagger_client** and **swagger_client.egg-info** copied it to my **virtualenv/lib/python3.X/site-packages** folder where all the rest of the packages I use are located. After that I could import swagger_client to all my Django files.

Answer (score 0):

You can install swagger in your project by below command. (**Python**)

```
pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/Yelp/bravado@swaggerpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
pip install zuora-swagger-client
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while following the docs for a partner company's internal API, and found that installing `swagger_client` was actually not the issue.

Swagger is often used for the documentation SDK examples, and is not an officially published package. Often the REST API endpoint itself for custom APIs is tech stack-agnostic, so you are able to use whatever best fits your existing languages/frameworks for interacting with API endpoints.

Answer (score -1):

This link clearly outlines things to be done. This is for anyone who is facing this issue

Download and install the API client library
To execute the sample you need to generate the Python library for the REST API which is generated through Swagger.

Follow these steps for the installation:

Go to https://editor.swagger.io.
Click File, then click Import URL.
Enter the Swagger URL for the Speech Services API: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/main/specification/cognitiveservices/data-plane/Speech/SpeechToText/stable/v3.1/speechtotext.json.
Click Generate Client and select Python.
Save the client library.
Extract the downloaded python-client-generated.zip somewhere in your file system.
Install the extracted python-client module in your Python environment using pip: pip install path/to/package/python-client.
The installed package has the name swagger_client. You can check that the installation worked using the command python -c "import swagger_client".

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/batch/python/README.md

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).