# how can i unpack a tuple in python 2 and why my this code is showing error?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to print each tuple member on next line

## Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT

```
import cmath

polar=cmath.polar(complex(raw_input()))
print *polar , sep='\n'
```

input:
1+2j
output:
2.23606797749979 
 1.1071487177940904
my output:
print *polar , sep='\n'
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use from \_\_future\_\_ import print\_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032697/how-to-use-from-future-import-print-function)

Comment: You can't use * expression with the print statement.
Also where have you defined sep?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code in python 3.7 latest version. It is working and no error.

```
import cmath

polar=cmath.polar(complex(input()))
print (*polar , sep='\n')
```