# Replacing printed output in python not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to make a program in python that **replaces** the printed value in the console with the next value, in essence making a rudimentary timer.

After looking through the web for a while, I landed on this bit of code:

```
import time

number = 0

while True:
    print(number, end = "\r")
    number += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

This would supposedly remove the previously printed number and replace it with a new one, but instead I got this output:

```
0123456789
```

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wobwvvj9XZA)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvgHY.png)

What is going on?

Comment: Share an image of your output rather than a video of it.

Comment: Is that IDLE? IDLE doesn't understand the `'\r'` character. Try in a terminal (although you may want to use `print(number, end='\r', flush=True)` because often the buffer waits for a newline before writing).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset cursor to the beginning of the same line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715594/how-to-reset-cursor-to-the-beginning-of-the-same-line-in-python)

Comment: @FHTMitchell, thanks a lot, it works in the terminal ... would have really liked to use the IDLE but I guess life is cruel.

Comment: this is more of an opinion you dont need to use idle, as far as features go it's pretty rudimentary compared to other python editors like pycharm (which has a great free community edition version) and if you like the interactive interpreter of idle you can use IPython which is console based but again has even more features

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite thanks for the tip, I'll have a look at some of those

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute the file in the command line or the terminal.

```
python3 counterl.py
```

This gave me the expected result.