# Print new output on same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I want to print the looped output to the screen on the same line.

How do I this in the simplest way for Python 3.x

I know this question has been asked for Python 2.7 by using a comma at the end of the line i.e. print I, but I can't find a solution for Python 3.x.

```
i = 0 
while i <10:
     i += 1 
     ## print (i) # python 2.7 would be print i,
     print (i) # python 2.7 would be 'print i,'
```

Screen output.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

---

What I want to print is:

```
12345678910
```

New readers visit this link aswell http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically

Comment: Related post - [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/493386/465053)

Answer (score 212, accepted):

From `help(print)`:

```
Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
```

You can use the `end` keyword:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 11):
...     print(i, end='')
... 
12345678910>>>
```

Note that you'll have to `print()` the final newline yourself.  BTW, you won't get "12345678910" in Python 2 with the trailing comma, you'll get `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Yes very true that print i, will have an inserted space. What would the code be for it behaving like python 2 with comma?

Comment: Same thing but with `end = ' '`.  Instead of ending every print "line" with nothing, you end it with a space.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and update. That makes so much more sense now. I read the help function a dozen times and wasn't obviously paying attention. :)

Answer (score 38):

*** for python 2.x ***

Use a trailing comma to avoid a newline.

```
print "Hey Guys!",
print "This is how we print on the same line."
```

The output for the above code snippet would be,

```
Hey Guys! This is how we print on the same line.
```

*** for python 3.x ***

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, end="<separator>") # <separator> = \n, <space> etc.
```

The output for the above code snippet would be (when `<separator> = " "`),

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: That only works in in python 2.x this post is for python 3.x print usage

Comment: that is leaving a space. "...Guys!<space>This is...". any workaround?

Comment: How to suppress the space which is inserted because of the comma in the first print statement?

Answer (score 14):

Similar to what has been suggested, you can do:

```
print(i, end=',')
```

> Output: 0,1,2,3,

Comment: what about last 3, ?

Answer (score 7):

```
print("single",end=" ")
print("line")
```

this will give output

```
single line
```

for the question asked use

```
i = 0 
while i <10:
     i += 1 
     print (i,end="")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something such as:

```
>>> print(''.join(map(str,range(1,11))))
12345678910
```

Comment: Read the question. print i, only works in python 2 not python 3.

Comment: Alright, I missed it. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> for i in range(1, 11):
...     print(i, end=' ')
...     if i==len(range(1, 11)): print()
... 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
>>>
```

This is how to do it so that the printing does not run behind the prompt on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take an example where you want to print numbers from 0 to n in the same line. You can do this with the help of following code.

```
n=int(raw_input())
i=0
while(i<n):
    print i,
    i = i+1
```

> At input, n = 5

```
Output : 0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Comment: @imo Actually his code doesn't answer the question, as the question explicitly asks for Python 3.x.    Code provided .. print i,  ..only works in Python 2