# Python print on same line after sleep

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I checked [Print new output on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032214/python-3-print-new-output-on-same-line/20544490#20544490)

but am still confused:

```
import time
print("HI ", end=""),
time.sleep(2)
print("BYE")
```

it does print HI BYE on the same line, but it prints all at once after the sleep. I want to print HI then sleep for 2 seconds and print BYE after the 2s.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: print ('hai'), is not yet completed and expecting for the next one to print that's your problem

Comment: I checked there's no problem with your code & it's running exactly as you said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flush your output:

```
impost sys
import time
print("HI ", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)
print('BYE')
```

If you write to file-like object, you need flush it:

```
file.flush()
```

in python 3.3 you can just add key-word parameter to print function:

```
print(smth, flush=True)
```