# Making two functions print their output on the same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

I'm making an interpreter, and I have a function called `parse()`. The `parse` function returns some output.

I'm making a command that prints two command's outputs on the same line instead of on separate lines.

I have the following code:

```
def print_command2(command):
    command = command.split("_") # The underscore separates the two commands
    command[0] = command[0].strip("! ") # The command is !
    print(parse(command[0])), # This should print the output of the first command
    print(parse(command[1])) # And this should print the second
```

I typed in the following command to test it:

```
! p Hello_p World
```

(`p` is the equivalent of Python's `print` command.)
But it outputs the following:

```
Hello

World
```

I want it to print this:

```
HelloWorld
```

What's wrong?

---

EDIT: The answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032214/python-3-print-new-output-on-same-line) prints the following:

```
Hello
World
```

So it doesn't work as wanted.

EDIT: Here's the `parse` function. Please don't mind the terrible code.

```
def parse(command):
    """Parses the commands."""
    if ';' in command:
        commands = command.split(";")
        for i in commands:
            parse(i)
    if '\n' in command:
        commands = command.split('\n')
        for i in commands:
            parse(i)
    elif command.startswith("q"):
        quine(command)
    elif command.startswith("p "):
        print_command(command)
    elif command.startswith("! "):
        print_command2(command)
    elif command.startswith("l "):
        try:
            loopAmount = re.sub("\D", "", command)
            lst = command.split(loopAmount)
            strCommand = lst[1]
            strCommand = strCommand[1:]
            loop(strCommand, loopAmount)
        except IndexError as error:
            print("Error: Can't put numbers in loop")
    elif '+' in command:
        print (add(command))
    elif '-' in command:
        print (subtract(command))
    elif '*' in command:
        print (multiply(command))
    elif '/' in command:
        print (divide(command))
    elif '%' in command:
        print (modulus(command))
    elif '=' in command:
        lst = command.split('=')
        lst[0].replace(" ", "")
        lst[1].replace(" ", "")
        stackNum = ''.join(lst[1])
        putOnStack(stackNum, lst[0])
    elif command.startswith("run "):
        command = command.replace(" ", "")
        command = command.split("run")
        run(command[1])
    elif command.startswith('#'):
        pass
    elif command.startswith('? '):
        stackNum = command[2]
        text = input("input> ")
        putOnStack(text, stackNum)
    elif command.startswith('@ '):
        stackNum = command[2]
        print(''.join(stack[int(stackNum)]))
    elif command.startswith("."):
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        print("Invalid command")
    return("")
```

**TL;DR:** I'm calling two functions. I want their output to print on the same line.

Comment: @vaultah It's still not working; it prints `Hello (newline) World`

Comment: From where are you taking the input? File or via `input`?

Comment: Can you verify that the string returned by the `parse()` function is not newline-terminated?

Comment: @BhargavRao Via input. I have a `prompt` function.

Comment: I have re-opened this (as I feel I had wrongly hammered it). There is a high likelihood of the string having `\n`. Try using `command.strip()` before the `split`

Comment: @JoelC I have this code in the `parse` function: `elif command.startswith("p "):
        print_command(command)`. And here's the code for the `print_command` function: `print(command[2:])`

Comment: Again, this shows the lack of a [MCVE]. We need further code to try and debug this problem. Do provide additional code if possible.

Comment: If the `print` statement is inside your `print_command` function, that is where you will need to make the change to the `print` statement as in the marked duplicate answer.

Comment: @BhargavRao What code do you need? Also, using `strip` before `split` did nothing.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample of the `parse` function? Could you try `print(parse(command[0]).strip())`?

Comment: @JoelC That didn't work either, unfortunately.

Comment: In that case, you will need to post a full section of code which can be run to show the issue you are having. Otherwise, we'll all just be working blind.

Comment: @JoelC I added the whole `parse` function.

Comment: The problem seems to be from `print_command`. Have a look at those once and try to use the tips in robert's answer.

Comment: @BhargavRao Aha, I found the problem. In the `print_command` function, I added `end=''` to the `print` command.

Comment: @BhargavRao Unfortunately, that messes up my interpreter, but I think I know how to fix _that_.

Comment: You made re-open the question though @vaultah and I had closed it correctly. Nevermind, do accept robert's answer if you feel so.

Comment: Have you considered using something like pyparsing to help you write your parser?

Comment: @shuttle87 No, but I prefer writing my parsers by hand :) (Might check pyparsing out though)

Comment: If this is a learning exercise by all means write it out by hand, however you will benefit greatly from adding some additional structure to the code as things get more complex.

Answer (score 0):

the `print()` function has extra arguments you can pass to it.  You are interested in `end`.

```
def test1():
    print('hello ', end='')


def test2():
    print('there', end='')


test1()
test2()


>>> 
hello there
>>>
```

It doesn't matter how many functions this comes from

Comment: wow, a ton of buried comments on the original question, and I see that 'end' was already brought up and rejected.  The question doesn't elaborate on why that doesn't have the desired effect though.