# How to write rows and columns (matrix) in python

Tags: python-3.x

My 12 year old is starting to learn Python. He is trying to write a rows and columns using 2 for loops. This is the code he wrote so far.

```
for rows in range(1, 6, 1):
print('something')
for col in range(1, 6, 1):
    print(str(col))
```

The desired output is as follows:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Where does the data come from? List? List of lists? You can suppress `print`'s automatic line break with the `end` parameter (`print("no linebreak pls", end="")`)

Comment: awesome!!! it works thanks much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python 3: print new output on same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032214/python-3-print-new-output-on-same-line)