# Printing 6 numbers on the same line with a for /range loop

Tags: python

I am having an issue printing random numbers to the same line, then printing the total of the 6 random numbers on the second print statement. Here is what i have so far.

```
import random
def main():

    randnums()

def randnums():
    for num in range(0, 6):
        num1 = random.randint(1,9) 
        print(str(num1))
        print(" The total is: ")

main()
```

Should look like this

```
  2 4 8 9 9 3 
  The total is 35
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your code because of its poor indentation but here are some things to take note of:

1. You need to have a variable which stores the total
2. Python print function defaults all strings to print out with a newline.

## Store total

This is simple, just add a variable outside of the for loop which adds the number:

```
def randnums():
    # Add this new variable
    total = 0
    for num in range(0, 6):
        num1 = random.randint(1, 9)
        total += num1
    # Print it out
    print("The total is:", total)
```

## Remove newline

For [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), it is simple to remove the newline. Just supply a new keyword argument to the print function and it will work:

```
def randnums():
    total = 0
    for num in range(0, 6):
        num1 = random.randint(1, 9)
        total += num1
        # End the string with a space. Also removes newline
        print(num1, end=" ")
    # Add a newline before printing again.
    print("\nThe total is:", total)
```

If you are using Python 2 in the future, you could do it two ways: Either import `print_function` from [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) or [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) with a comma:

Import from `__future__`:

```
# Note that this import must come first
from __future__ import print_function
import random

def main():
    randnums()

def randnums():
    total = 0
    for num in range(0, 6):
        num1 = random.randint(1, 9)
        total += num1
        print(num1, end=" ")
    print("\nThe total is:", total)

main()
```

Or use a comma:

```
import random

def main():
    randnums()

def randnums():
    total = 0
    for num in range(0, 6):
        num1 = random.randint(1, 9)
        total += num1
        # The comma is put after what you want to print. It also adds a space
        print num1,
    print "\nThe total is:", total

main()
```

The output:

```
3 9 8 2 4 1
The total is: 27
```

Comment: +1 These are all excellent solutions, the only other one I would suggest would be to store them in a list, then print the whole list, which I would expect to be faster than six separate calls to print individual characters, but it's less pythonic and in this basic case wholly unnecessary.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Just tested some code. Using a list is actually slower. I am guessing it's because lists are more expensive compared to ints due to its expandability.

Comment: PyCharm agrees with you, in the naive case. With list comprehension, it's much, much faster:
100000 elements (in sec)

Time for print 0.906000

Time for list 0.994000 (0.011000 to build list, 0.983000 to print)

Time for list comp 0.024000

Comment: Try `print ''.join([repr(random.randint(1,9)) + " " for num in xrange(count)])` :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have better luck if you indent your code correctly.

```
def randnums():
    for num in range(0, 6):
        num1 = random.randint(1,9) 
        print(str(num1), end=" ")
    print()
    print(" The total is: ")
```

And to you need to actually accumulate the total in a variable which is trivial because summing is very basic and everything basic is very well documented.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is as follows:

```
import sys
def randnums():
    sum = 0
    for num in range(0, 6):
        num1 = random.randint(1,9) 
        sum += num1
        sys.stdout.write(str(num1)+" ")
    print("\nThe total is: "+str(sum))
```

OR (if Python 3)

```
def randnums():
    sum=0
    for num in range(0, 6):
        num1 = random.randint(1,9) 
        sum += num1
        print(str(num1), end=' ')
    print("\nThe total is: "+str(sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Print new output on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032214/python-3-print-new-output-on-same-line)

In addition:

1. Make sure to fix your indentation; python is very strict about it.
2. You need to either save the numbers in a list or accumulate the sum in a variable. Otherwise after you print num1, it's gone.

   ```
   import random

   total = 0
   for num in range(0, 6):
     num1 = random.randint(1,9)
     total += num1
     print(num1, end=' ')
   print('\nThe total is:', total)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7

```
 import random
    def main():

        randnums()

    def randnums():
        sum=0
        for num in range(0, 6):
            num1 = random.randint(1,9) 
            print(str(num1))
            sum+=num1,
        print
        print(" The total is: %d" % sum)

    main()
```

In python 3

```
def randnums():
        sum=0
        for num in range(0, 6):
            num1 = random.randint(1,9) 
            print("{}".format(num1)),
            sum+=num1
        print
        print("{}{}".format(" The total is: " , sum))
```