# How to convert while loop int output into string (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to using python so I apologize if I do not use the correct terms. I am writing a simple program to where the user inputs a decimal number and the program converts it to a binary number. So far I have:

```
remainder=0
decimal_number= int(input('Enter the decimal number:'))

while decimal_number != 0:
    (decimal_number, remainder) = divmod(decimal_number,2)
    print(remainder)
```

If I input 11, the output looks like

```
1
1
0
1
```

My question is how can I format it to be in one single line, and how can I reverse is so it is written correctly? (ex. from the output shown above to '1011'). I am also aware there is a binary function, but I am not allowed to use it in my program.

Comment: probably use `print(remainder, end='')`

Comment: See [this question for some good facts about printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032214/print-new-output-on-same-line). But basically, the `print` function takes keyword parameters `sep` and `end` that default to `' '` and `'\n'`, respectively. You can pass `print` whatever you want...

Comment: Thank you! This gave me the output of '1101', but how do I reverse it to look like '1011'?

Comment: since you are a beginner, I encourage you to try to solve it on your own. Try putting it in a data structure, like a `str` or even a `list` of numbers, then try figuring out how to print from the *end* of the list using a loop and indexing, i.e. `my_list[i]` is the *ith* value of `my_list`.

Comment: @BarbaraJ, if you get the output as a list, you could use the `reverse` function on the list, like in this answer [How can I reverse a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3940128/1248974)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
import sys
remainder=0
decimal_number= int(input('Enter the decimal number:'))
    while decimal_number != 0:
    (decimal_number, remainder) = divmod(decimal_number,2)
    sys.stdout.write(str(remainder))
```

That should print everything on the same line :)

If you want some explanation,

we import the sys module first which gives us access to the stdout.write() method.

This method doesn't automatically insert a new line so it fits your purpose.
We also convert the integer to string since the sys.stdout.write() method will not accept integer values.

Answer (score 0):

While @Manan's answer will print the values on the same line, it is not very pythonic and does not reverse the result as you require.

I would suggest storing the values you need and then reversing them:

```
remainder=0

decimal_number= int(input('Enter the decimal number:'))

result = ''
while decimal_number != 0: 
    (decimal_number, remainder) = divmod(decimal_number,2)
    result += str(remainder)
print(result[::-1])
```

Alternatively you could repeatedly append to the beginning of your stored result to achieve the reversal:

```
remainder=0

decimal_number= int(input('Enter the decimal number:'))

result = ''
while decimal_number != 0: 
    (decimal_number, remainder) = divmod(decimal_number,2)
    result = str(remainder) + result
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

To print binary results in a single line use end='' as second argument in the print function to prevent printing a new line after printing the result.
Or you can declare a variable and concatenate the string value of binary result and print is out side of the loop, Like

```
binaryResult = ''
while decimal_number != 0: 
    (decimal_number, remainder) = divmod(decimal_number,2)
    binaryResult += str(remainder)
print(result)
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

When you run following script, be aware the indent.
you will get: 1101

```
def test():
    remainder=0

    decimal_number= int(input('Enter the decimal number:'))

    while decimal_number != 0: 

        (decimal_number, remainder) = divmod(decimal_number,2)
        print (remainder,end="")         

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

If you have much much bigger binary value need to be reverse, binary tree(data structure) can help with. But list is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple and clean approach

```
decimal_number= input('Enter the decimal number:')
binary = bin(decimal_number)
print binary[2:]
```

Output

```
Enter the decimal number:10
1010
```

Answer (score 0):

[print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function that accepts keyword `end` to specify how the end of each output should be handled. The default `end` argument is the `newline` character `'\n'`: `end=’\n’`, which we can change to be `''`, essentially nothing.

The other issue to print from most significant bit (LSB) to least significant bit (MSB) could be handled building a list and print it with the [reversed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0322/) function.

Putting it all together:

```
remainder=0

decimal_number= int(input('Enter the decimal number:'))

result = []

while decimal_number != 0: 
    (decimal_number, remainder) = divmod(decimal_number,2)
    result.append(remainder)

for n in reversed(result):
    print(n, end='')
print()
```

demo:

```
Enter the decimal number:11
1011
```

Hope this helps.