# Configure output screen in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In visual studio code using python .. I want to clean the output window so I want two things :

1 - Hide the file path in the output window

2- When i execute the code the output print the result one after one  ... I want the recent code over right the previous one

[image]

Comment: Is this helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032214/print-new-output-on-same-line. For `end` you can use `\r`

Comment: Sorry ... i didn't mean that   .. what i want is about settings in visual studio code