# How to split integers with a comma

Tags: python

I want to print all of the integers in the range 1000-3000 that are even and then print them in one line, each seperated by a comma. This is my code so far:

```
for i in range (1000,3001):
      s = str(i)
      if i % 2 == 0:
            print (i)
```

If I try to add the split() function, this error occurs:
'int' object has no attribute 'split'

How can I do this?

Comment: Just use `print (i, end=',')`

Comment: It helps to understand what given function does before trying to use it. Shotgun development barely works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print new output on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032214/print-new-output-on-same-line)

Comment: @Sheldore: except for the last print, ofcourse.

Comment: Given that it's not a massive range... you could probably get away with: `print(*range(1000, 3001, 2), sep=',')` here

Answer (score 2):

As simple as:

```
print(','.join([str(i) for i in range(1000, 3001, 2)]))
```

Or alternatively:

```
print(*range(1000, 3001, 2), sep=',')
```

You don't need to check for even numbers, since you can just print every second number starting with an even number.

Answer (score 0):

Te answer to this is as simple as follows:

```
out = [str(i) for i in range(1000, 3001) if i % 2 == 0]

print(",".join(out))
```

The output reads:

```
1000, 1002, ..., 3000
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it works fine :

```
even_number_list=[]    # taking an empty list to store even numbers

for i in range(1000,3001):
        if(i%2==0):
                even_number_list.append(i)   # appending even numbers in our list

print(*even_number_list,sep=',')            # unpacking list with values seperated by comma
```