# Python: print/combine output to one line

Tags: python

A similar question with [Print new output on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032214/print-new-output-on-same-line), which does not answer my question.

I wonder how (with python 2 and 3) to print all to one line.
e.g., By running:

```
print("Result of:\t")

mylist1=[]
mylist2=[]
name = "class_1"

for i in range(-5, 0):
    mylist1.append(i)
for j in range(1, 6):
    mylist2.append(j)
print(name+"\t")
print(mylist1+"\t"+mylist2)
```

What I got:

```
Result of:  
class_1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-1e34909da6d3> in <module>
     10     mylist2.append(j)
     11 print(name+"\t")
---> 12 print(mylist1+"\t"+mylist2)
     13 

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

However, what I want is to print them in one line separated with "\t":

```
Result of:    class_1    [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1]    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

which solution is usually used for this case?

Comment: Use the `sep` and `end` arguments of [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: BTW, `mylist1=[]` - `for i in range(-5, 0):` - `mylist1.append(i)` is a complicated way to write `mylist1 = list(range(-5, 0))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can use `sep` argument to different values without using `+`.
- You also need to cast `list` to `str` to print with `[]`

```py
mylist1=[]
mylist2=[]
name = "class_1"

for i in range(-5, 0):
    mylist1.append(i)
for j in range(1, 6):
    mylist2.append(j)
print("Result of:", name, str(mylist1), str(mylist2), sep='\t')
```

Comment: Or in current versions of Python with an f-string: `print(f'Result of:\t{name}\t{mylist1}\t{mylist2}')`

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist1=[]
mylist2=[]
name = "class_1"

for i in range(-5, 0):
    mylist1.append(i)
for j in range(1, 6):
    mylist2.append(j)
print("Result of:", name, str(mylist1), str(mylist2), sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

For python 3.x

```
print(name, sep="\t")
```

For python 2.x (in python 2.x print is not a function rather it is keyword)

Still achieve the same in python 2.x

```
from __future__ import print_function
print_function(name, sep="\t")
```

or

```
print "\t".join(list[name])
```

### Edited (added examples):

for python 3.x

```
print("Result of:", name, str(mylist1), str(mylist2), sep='\t')
```

for python 2.x

```
 print "\t".join([name, str(mylist1), str(mylist2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(list1,"\t",list2)
```

This gives the desired output

Comment: No, it does not