# I'd like to print without a newline when calling a method

Tags: python, methods, printing, newline

I'm calling a simple little method that prints an initial statement and then a period every second. It's printing each new dot on a new line, however, and I want them all on one line, like this: 'Checking. . . . . .'

When I follow the print statements with a comma, or if I use `sys.stdout.write()`, the method hangs until the entire loop is complete, and then prints  all at once.

Here's my code. Using python 2.4.3 - don't have a choice about that, I'm afraid.

```
class WaitTimer(object):

    def timer(self, time, countDown=0):
        if countDown == 0:
            print "\nChecking.",
        if countDown <= time:
            countDown += 1
            print ".",

            self.timer(time, countDown)

wait = WaitTimer()

wait.timer(5)
```

Comment: use `sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to have a call to `sys.stdout.flush()`, when you want the data to be displayed. I don't think `print "blah",` will do a flush.

Comment: `print "blah"` includes a newline, and therefore a flush.

Comment: But, not print "blah", as I wrote.

Comment: oh, you are right- haven't noticed the comma. better write "with a comma"

Comment: That's the ticket. When I tried it with sys.stdout.write() I only flushed, once, outside the loop. putting the flush inside the loop, after each sys.stdout.write(), did it.  Thanks Owen and Elazar