# How to use \r to print on same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout, carriage-return

I have made a downloader:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function, division, absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
import argparse
try:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib.request import urlopen

# {{ Argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog='downloader',
    description='a featureful downloader'
)

parser.add_argument(
    '-o',
    dest='outputfile'
)

parser.add_argument(
    '-r',
    dest='remotefile'
)

downloader = parser.parse_args()
# }}

# {{ default local filename
if downloader.outputfile:
    default_output_file = downloader.outputfile
else:
    default_output_file = os.path.split(downloader.remotefile)[-1]
# }}

u = urlopen(downloader.remotefile)
meta = u.info()
file_size  = int(dict(meta.items())['Content-Length'])
print("Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (default_output_file, file_size))

with open(default_output_file, 'wb') as f:
    file_size_dl = 0
    block_sz = 8192
    while True:
        buffer = u.read(block_sz)
        if not buffer:
            break

        file_size_dl += len(buffer)
        f.write(buffer)
        status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
        status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
        print(status)
```

A sample run of this script would be:

```
python3 downloader.py -o ubuntu.iso -r http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso
```

And a sample output will be:

```
Downloading: ubuntu.iso Bytes: 832569344
      8192  [0.00%]
     16384  [0.00%]
     24576  [0.00%]
     32768  [0.00%]
     40960  [0.00%]
     49152  [0.01%]
     57344  [0.01%]
     65536  [0.01%]
     73728  [0.01%]
     81920  [0.01%]
     90112  [0.01%]
     98304  [0.01%]
    106496  [0.01%]
    114688  [0.01%]
    122880  [0.01%]
    131072  [0.02%]
    139264  [0.02%]
    147456  [0.02%]
    155648  [0.02%]
    163840  [0.02%]
```

Note that as the loop goes the output is printed on a separate lines. I know I can use `\r` *(carriage return)* to do that. But I have confusion where and how to use that.

Comment: and of [Print in one line dynamically. Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3249524)

Comment: '\r' means "go to the beginning of the line". Put it where you need it.

Answer (score 27):

Put the `\r` at the beginning or end of your printed string, e.g. `'\rthis string will start at the beginning of the line'`. or `'the next string will start at the beginning of the line\r'`. Conceptually, `\r` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line and then keeps outputting characters as normal.

You also need to tell print not to automatically put a newline character at the end of the string. In python3, you can use `end=""` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space) previous stackoverflow answer.

Alternatively, instead of using print you can do `import sys` and `sys.stdout.write('whatever')`, which sends only the exact characters to stdout without an implicit newline. You'll probably also want to use `sys.stdout.flush()`, without which it will store characters in a buffer rather than printing them immediately.

Answer (score 12):

Add an `, end="\r"` to you print function.  Also make sure your printed data has enough space to overwrite the previous printed data or be of the same length since just moving to the same line would not automatically clear the previous contents.

Comment: Cute idea to use 'end', but I prefer to print the '\r' right before printing my value, not after. That way, anything else that gets printed (e.g. a traceback) doesn't overwrite the last printed value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sys.stdout.write`:

```
import time
import sys

def timer(t=5):
    t0 = time.time()
    now = t0
    while now-t0 < t:
        now = time.time()
        timestr = '\r%%%i\t' %(100*(now-t0)/t)
        sys.stdout.write(timestr)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
```