# How to print number dynamically with string

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I am trying to print number dynamically.

I tried it according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3249539/3871910)

I want to print something like:
`numbers: 1 2 3 4 5`

but instead it is printing: `numbers: 63  numbers: 25  numbers: 57  numbers: 43  numbers: 9`

here is my code:

```
a= range(1,53)
for i in xrange(5):
    b = a[random.randint(0,len(a)-i)]
    a.remove(b)
    print "Your numbers:", b,
```

I know problem is `,` after string.

How to fix it?

Comment: What is the list `a` ?

Comment: a = range(1,53) @AnandSKumar

Comment: What do you think `print "Your numbers:", b,` inside of your loop does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only print`'Your numbers'` string before the `for` loop , and print the actual numbers inside, your current code prints `'Your numbers'` for each number.

Example -

```
print "Your numbers:",
for i in xrange(5):
    b = a[random.randint(0,len(a)-i)]
    a.remove(b)
    print b,
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. But as always there are downvotes. I think down vote are only if I ask some question without research effort or showing my own efforts.