# How to print on the same line in Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to print text on the same line in Python?

For instance, instead of having

```
1
2
3
```

I would have

```
1 2 3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want the exact *opposite* of printing on the next line? What have you tried? There are dozens of questions related to this already.

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically

Comment: @michelpri not exactly the same as what has been asked. What you link does is overwriting a line that has been printed

Answer (score 6):

Assuming this is Python 2...

```
print '1',
print '2',
print '3'
```

Will output...

```
1 2 3
```

The comma (`,`) tells Python to not print a new line.

Otherwise, if this is Python 3, use the `end` argument in the `print` function.

```
for i in (1, 2, 3):
    print(str(i), end=' ') # change end from '\n' (newline) to a space.
```

Will output...

```
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

when putting a separator (comma) your problem is easily fixed. But obviously I'm over four years too late.

print(1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 2):

**Removing the newline character from print function.**

Because the print function automatically adds a *newline* character to the string that is passed, you would need to remove it by using the "end=" at the end of a string.

SAMPLE BELOW:

```
print('Hello')
print('World')
```

Result below.

```
Hello
World
```

SAMPLE Of "end=" being used to remove the "newline" character.

```
print('Hello', end= ' ')
print('World')
```

Result below.

```
Hello World
```

By adding the ' ' two single quotation marks you create the space between the two words, Hello and World, (Hello' 'World') - I believe this is called a "blank string".