# Python - Print alphabet in order on same line

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to print all capital letters of the alphabet on the same line, but I keep getting a syntax error.

```
for c in range(0, 26):
    print(chr(ord('A', end '')+c))
```

Comment: ord function takes only one argument. You can specify ord('A') and that will give you the Unicode point for  'A' which is a one character string. That is why you are getting a syntax error.

Comment: A tip of asking a good question: instead of saying *keep getting a syntax error*, show the exact error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print on the same line in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905032/how-to-print-on-the-same-line-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

[`ord()` takes a single character](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord), and converts it into it's Unicode code point. It only takes one parameter. It looks like you meant to place `, end ''` in the `print()` call. Here's the updated code:

```
for c in range(0, 26):
    print(chr(ord('A')+c), end='')
```

Comment: I believe the end '' is for the print function

Comment: This partially works but. But end' ' is there to try to place the words on the same line.  The code you gave me prints on different lines and I'm trying to get an output of ABCDEF.......

Comment: @BB956 Just updated my answer, you just placed it inside the `odr()` call by accident.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inbuild function called string for you to import

In order to print all the alphabets with uppercase you can do this:

```
import string
print string.ascii_uppercase
```

If you want to put a space in between the letters you can do this:

```
import string
line = ""
for i in list(string.ascii_uppercase):
    line = line + i + " "
print line
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: I'm sure it helped but this doesn't answer his question... Why the syntax error?

Comment: @TerryA I am not sure... but I am sure it wont print out all of the uppercase even if there isn't a SyntaxError

Comment: @rcw I think you meant the last line to be `print line`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
import string

for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:print(letter, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like most of the answers on this have individual pieces correct, but not the whole solution.

I would recommend:

```
result = ""
for c in range(0, 26):
    result += chr(ord('A')+c)

print(result)
```

The issue is two-fold. Syntax issue is caused by `, end ''` as a parameter to ord (it only takes one parameter). Printing across multiple lines is caused by Python's built-in print function always appending new lines. To resolve that, you can just store the results in a string and print that final string when you are done building it. You could also consider using an array such as `ArrayVariableName.append(chr(ord('A')+c))`, and then `print(''.join(ArrayVariableName))`. (I haven't tested that, but it should work.)