# Hi, am new to Python and trying to print the following:

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create the following:

```
88888888
7777777
666666
```

.. and so on

Below is the code that I have written:

```
i = 8
for a in range(i):
    for b in range(i):
        print (str(i))
    i = i - 1
```

with this code, I am getting the numbers on a new line. I want all the 8s on one line, all the 7s on one line, etc.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the documentation for the `print` function, and in particular the `end` parameter to that function.

Comment: You could just build a string in the loop and then print it at the end. If you're interested, this is a one liner that will do what you're looking for `'\n'.join(str(i)*i for i in range(1,9))[::-1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in one line dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Comment: @Rogalski That's not what OP wanted for output, they want it joined with new lines.

Answer (score 4):

One particularly short wait you can get the desired result is

```
for i in range(8, 0, -1):
    print(str(i) * i)
```

`range(8, 0, -1)` gives you the sequence of numbers equivalent to `[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`. You convert the number into a string, and multiplying a string by an integer i repeats it it i times. So for example, the number `8` gets converted to a string `'8'` and `'8' * 8 = '88888888'`. `print()` ends with a newline by default, giving us the result:

```
88888888
7777777
666666
55555
4444
333
22
1
```

Comment: This is the most elegant and pythonic answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to bother with my silly question. However with few hit and trials i found the answer. Please ignore my question.

```
i= 8
for a in range(i):
    for b in range(i):
            print (i, end=' ')
    print(" ")
    i = i - 1
```

Comment: Good job! It's nice to see someone answer their own question. Keep at it!

Comment: The last `print()` can be without arguments, the last `i = i - 1` can be thrown away. The print in the loop should print `a`, and the first range should loop backward. Or you can use the while-loop with the last `i = i -1`.