# Python: Printing Third Letter of Sentence

Tags: python

```
def main (): 
    sentence=input("Please enter a sentence:")
    print("Original Sentence:",sentence)
    sentencelenght=len(sentence)
    for i in range(0, sentencelenght, 3): 
        print("Every third letter:", i)
main()
```

I am at this point and my output is a bunch of numbers, please explain how I can fix this.

Note we have learned for, while loops, if/or statements more basic stuff. Nothing too complicated.

Comment: print `sentence[i]` rather than `i`

Comment: bash-4.1$ python hw4_part2.py
Please enter a sentence:Thanks for the help
Original Sentence: Thanks for the help
Every third letter: T
Every third letter: n
Every third letter:  
Every third letter: r
Every third letter: h
Every third letter: h
Every third letter: p
bash-4.1$

Comment: My answer needs to come out in this form

Comment: The output you obtained is the characters in the sentence at positions {0, 3, 6, 9, ...}, which is what the program does. If you update your question with an example input and expected output, people may be able to understand what you want better.

Comment: This is correct but I want my answer to print, Every third letter: Im....etc

Comment: What do you mean ? Where is 'm' in the sentence 'Thanks for the help' ?

Comment: If you meant you want only the letters, use `print sentence[i]`

Comment: print("Every third letter:",sentence[i])

Comment: I did but it does not work

Comment: To reiterate: please give an example input and output. I and the people answering below are not able to understand the requirements.

Comment: My answer is coming out as third letter= i, third letter= m and such

Comment: I would like to print out the letters in one row.

Comment: The use `print(sentence[i], end="")`. More details at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically

Answer (score 4):

It's because you are using `i`, not the character at that position.  Change that line to this:

```
print("Every third letter:", sentence[i])
```

That is not the most efficient way to print every third letter, however.  You don't need the loop; just use `print(sentence[::3])`.  That works because a slice is `[start:stop:step]`.  We are leaving `start` empty, so it defaults to the beginning.  We are leaving `stop` empty, so it defaults to the end.  `step`, we are defining as `3`, so it goes from the beginning to the end using every third letter.

Comment: Only problem with this way is that I do not think we are allowed to use that method

Answer (score 2):

You can use slices to print every third letter (starting from the first letter):

```
print(sentence[::3])
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you cannot use slicing and need to use your own code, if you want to print every third character *starting from the third*, start the range an `2` and keep your step of 3 printing each `sentence[i]` though the loop:

```
def main ():
    sentence = input("Please enter a sentence:")
    print("Original Sentence:",sentence)
    # start at the third character
    for i in range(2,  len(sentence), 3):
        # access the string by index 
        print("Every third letter:", sentence[i])
```

Output:

```
In [2]: main()
Please enter a sentence:001002003
Original Sentence: 001002003
Every third letter: 1
Every third letter: 2
Every third letter: 3
```