# Pause during print python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I wonder if it is possible to pause during printing text in python 3.x on the same line? For example, I might want to print a word, and then pause before printing the next word.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood something, you can just print a word (check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically), then sleep. Repeat as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
import time
print("Hello,", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("World!")
```

The `end=""` tells the code to end the `print()` command with `""` rather than `"\n"` in case you were wondering.