# Print in single line in python using map() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to read an integer, and without using any string methods, I want to print something like this using the `map()` function:

```
123..N
```

For Example:

```
N:5  
output:12345
```

And not:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5
```

I have already read the following answer, which is not what i want. i want to use map() function which is not used in the answer given below

[Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Comment: @vaultah I disagree with the dup closure, but, this isn't a pearl of a question either, a custom close reason might suffice?

Comment: @vaultah: Why did you close this question as duplicate? This is a genuine question!

Comment: It isn't genuine, it a badly formatted question with no attempt by your part and no justification on why exactly you might need such quirky behavior. It probably isn't a dupe (unless I missed one answer) but it also isn't the best you could do.

Comment: @Jim you have the privilege to reopen questions.

Comment: @vaultah yup, but I don't like doing that without first consulting the one who closed it :-)

Comment: @TonyMathew sorry for closing your unclear question as dupe of a question with several potential solutions.

Comment: @TonyMathew qua functionality, the question is very easy to answer (and answered in the link you mention). Why do you want to do it with `map()`, and why no string methods?

Comment: Why not use list comprehension and `join` or if you must use map, `''.join(map(str, range(1, N+1)))` which is almost identical to a comment made on xortion's answer to the linked question.

Comment: I came up with two solutions: ','.join([str(x) for x in xrange(5)]) and ','.join(map(str, xrange(5)). I assume that the comprehension list is the fastest and the most pythonic solution. However I'm wondering if there is something more efficient

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(i, end="")
```

## You Welcome :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
from sys import stdin
N = int(stdin.read())

print ''.join(map(str,range(1,N+1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

the exact solution for this is

```
import math
def get_my_number(num):
    my_num = 0
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        digits = int(math.log10(i))+1  # count number of digits in number
        my_num = my_num * (10 ** digits) + i
    return my_num 
print (get_my_number(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using python 2.7, just use `;` at end of print statement if you want to print in single line.

Example:

```
for a in range(0,4):
  print '*',
```

it will produce the following output,

```
 * * * *
```

or if if you are using python 3.7, just use `end=' '` in print statement as second argument.

Example:

```
for a in range(0,4):
      print('*', end=' ')
```

it will produce the following output,

```
 * * * *
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this on python 2:

from **future** import print_function

map(lambda y:print (y,end=""),[x for x in range(1,int(input())+1)])