# Python specific "same line" printing

Tags: python, printing

I'm searching for printing this :

```
random_numbers = [1, 5, 25, 4, 60]

print("Numbers are : ") 

for elem in random_numbers :
    print(elem, end=' ')
```

and the result have to be like this :

```
Numbers are : 1 5 25 4 60
```

So on the same line, with space and no quote.  I searched for this on several forums and try to put in a function and call it right after printing "Numbers are : " but nothing worked, please help!

Comment: `print("Numbers are : ", end='')`

Comment: your print statement looks weird. try: print elem, " "

Comment: Closing as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically). To get what you want use `print("Numbers are :", end= ' ')`

Comment: @melgart The OP is using Python3.x

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed when i wrote the exact same code but with print("Numbers are : ", end = " ") it's working !