# Python carriage return

Tags: python, python-2.7, carriage-return

I am using Python 2.7.13(in Kali 4.9.0 amd64), and I have tried every variation of the print() statement that I can find(with the proper **future** import statements), and I am ending up with OK on a newline everytime. Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(0, 10000):
print("\rOK", end="")
```

I have tried:

- single quotes instead of double for end=""
- using Python 2.x syntax instead of importing print_function and using 3.0 syntax
- end='\r' end="\r"
- a space in between the quotes of end=""

When I used the 2.7 syntax, I was able to get the output to stay on the same line but still printing in a row, when I try to use a carriage return to return the cursor to the beginning position(and overwrite previous output), it inserts a newline, even with a terminating comma in my print statement. 
I have read Question [3249524](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically), along with well over a dozen other explanations for this problem.  I have also tried using the sys.stdout functions instead:

```
import sys

for i in range(10):
sys.stdout.write("\rCountdown: %d" % i)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

The output of both programs is still on a newline every time. I am at a loss as to how to get it to print in the same place on the same line. Thanks to anyone who can illuminate this issue.

Comment: What shell/terminal manager are you using? They may not properly handle carriage returns. I can make this work on, for example bash on Ubuntu on Windows just fine, as long as I put a `time.sleep` in between each print so I can see the numbers change slowly.

Comment: ShadowRanger I was using Spyder but now I am running everything from bash directly and have completely uninstalled Spyder and stopped using it.  The carriage return works exactly as it should when running the script from the command line, I suspect a lot of the people having the carriage return issue are running their scripts directly in their IDE console, and not from the command line.

Comment: That's exactly why I asked. I've heard of similar issues in a variety of custom shells (many of them integrated into IDEs). You also see issues with `multiprocessing` scripts in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I wanted to display some text scrolling sideways. Putting the `\r` at the beginning of the print statement was what I was looking for - if you put it at the end of the line nothing is displayed. I guess the carriage return behaves line like a `Ctrl-u` and not a true carriage return. :-/

Here's my example...

```py
import time


def sideways_scroll(string, display_length):
    string_length = len(string)

    for i in range(string_length):
        subset = string[i:i + display_length]
        print(f'\r{subset}', end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Adjust the delay time as desired


# Example usage
string = 'This is a Simple Sideways Scrolling "Hello, World" Message! '
display_length = 5
sideways_scroll(string, display_length)
```