# formatting floating point numbers in python on the same line from a list

Tags: python, format

I have a list of floats like following:

```
numbers = [23.23, 0.123334987, 1, 4.223, 9887.2]
```

I want to format it so that I could print up to 4 decimal places. So, I wrote the following code:

```
for x in numbers:
    print("{:10.04f}".format(x))
```

It prints following, i.e., each number in a separate line.

```
   23.2300
    0.1233
    1.0000
    4.2230
 9887.2000
```

However, I want to print all of them on the same line. Using following code, I could achieve this.

```
print('{:10.4f}{:10.4f}{:10.4f}{:10.4f}{:10.4f}'.format(numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2],numbers[3],numbers[4]))
```

And I got this:

```
   23.2300    0.1233    1.0000    4.2230 9887.2000
```

My question is: Is there any better way to achieve this without explicitly writing each element of the list using a loop? I have a list of 110 entries and writing each explicitly each element so many times is painful.

Comment: set the `end` in your print call: `print("{:10.04f}".format(x), end=' ')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Comment: I got syntax error, If I do this.

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Yeah, I just checked in python3, it worked fine. previously, I was using python 2.7, Anyways, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
print(' '.join("{:10.04f}".format(x) for x in numbers))
```

See [String join()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)

Within the join(), we apply the format to each element in the list of numbers.

Comment: This should produce the results you want. The square brackets are optional though.

Comment: Right, removed the square brackets

Answer (score 2):

The print built-in methon has an "end" keyword argument which defaults to a linebreak. You just need to replace it with a space or tab, like so:

```
print("{:10.04f}".format(x), end="\t")
```

Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print for more information on it.