# Print all the list values in a single row or single line in python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I am using the below code in python to print the values in the list in a single row, but it prints everything in a new line.

```
for abc in values: 
   print ','.join(abc)
```

Desired output:

```
S,t,r,e,e,t
N,o
Y,e,s
```

Comment: What does `values` look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using python 2. If this is the case, you can add a trailing comma after your print statement:

```
>>> for abc in ['street','No', 'Yes']:
...     print ','.join(abc),
... 
s,t,r,e,e,t N,o Y,e,s
```

If you were using Python 3, you can then use the extra argument `end` in the print function:

```
>>> for abc in ['street','No', 'Yes']:
...     print(','.join(abc), end='')
... 
s,t,r,e,e,tN,oY,e,s>>>
```

Note that this does not include a trailing new line.

The Python 3 method can be accomplished in Python 2 by inserting `from __future__ import print_statement` in the first line of your program.