# How can I remove last character printed? Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove the ',' before the '<', and the last ',' that is being printed, but I'm not sure how.

It's like I'm repeating a print command, but I'd like the last element being printed to follow a different command.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
for i in a:
  if i < 5:
    print(i, end=' ,')
print('<', end=' ')
for i in a:
  if i > 5:
    print(i, end=' ,')
```

This is what is being printed:

```
1 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,< 8 ,13 ,21 ,34 ,55 ,89 ,
```

I want to remove those extra commas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator expression with the `sep` parameter for `print` to print `' ,'` as a separator instead of an ending string.

Change:

```
for i in a:
  if i > 5:
    print(i, end=' ,')
```

to:

```
print(*(i for i in a if i > 5), sep=' ,', end='')
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me the sep feature, but i'm curious to know why is it necessary an * at the beggining of the print command

Comment: The `*` operator is unpacking the items from the output of the generator expression so that the items can be passed as individual arguments to the `print` function. You can see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

A bit verbose but works:

```
 >>> a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
 >>> ", ".join(str(n) for n in a if n < 5) + " < " + ", ".join(str(n) for n in a if n >= 5)
'1, 1, 2, 3 < 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89'
```

This concatenates string and makes use of [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) which is useful to handle such comma-separated sequences smartly

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last item of the array when iterating, then just print the last element at the end.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
for i in a[:-1]:    # Iterate to n-1 element
  if i < 5:
    print(i, end=' ,')
print('<', end=' ')
for i in a[:-1]:    # Iterate to n-1 element
  if i > 5:
    print(i, end=' ,')
print(a[-1])        # Print last element
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str.join` method to combine combine a bunch of strings into one, separated by the string you call it on. That will let you get your numbers separated by commas without adding an extra one on the end of each loop.

Here's how I'd do it all in one line:

```
print(" ,".join(str(n) for n in a if n < 5), "<", " ,".join(str(n) for n in a if n > 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.join(), .strip(), .replace()`

```
s = ''.join(str(a))
s = s.strip('[]')
s = s.replace(' 5,',' <')
print(s)
# 1, 1, 2, 3, < 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89
```