# Python - Print multiple functions in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

So when searching on google, the only think I found was printing print() functions all in one line. What I want to do is print multiple functions (like the def function1():) type of function.

```
if choice == "y":
      dice = input("What are the face values of the dice?")
      for c in dice:
        if c == "1":
          dot1()
```

I want to be able to print a possible dot2(), or dot3() if the choice is 2, or 3 on that same line. Is that possible? Right now dot1(), 2, and 3 looks like:

```
def dot1():
  print()
  print(" * ")
  print()
  return()


def dot2():
  print("*")
  print()
  print("  *")
  return()


def dot3():
  print("*")
  print(" *")
  print("  *")
  return()
```

If so please let me know! Also if you would like more code as an example let me know. This is really bugging me haha

Comment: The question is not clear. Write the expected and present output.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python#10308

Comment: Question is unclear. But this will help you [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically) , if it doesn't, be more specific of what you want

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to print the dot patterns of the dice faces?

```
def dot_pattern(c):  
    dice_repr = {1: '\n *\n\n',
             2: '*\n\n  *',
             3: '*\n *\n  *',
             4: '* *\n\n* *',
             5: '* *\n *\n* *',
             6: '* *\n* *\n* *'}  
    return dice_repr[c]

for c in range(1, 7):
    print(dot_pattern(c))
    print()
```

#### output:

Output

```
 *



*

  *

*
 *
  *

* *

* *

* *
 *
* *

* *
* *
* *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dice_dict = {
        1: dot1,
        2: dot2,
        3: dot3
}

dice_dict[1]() # loads function dot1.
```