# Using time.sleep() in Python, I'd like to print strings in the same line

Tags: python, time, import, module

Using `time.sleep()` method in Python, I've been trying to print strings in a same line. 
Result I want is printing five "." in a line one by one every second.

I've tried `end=''` with print line, but it appeared together 5 seconds later.

Here is my code.

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    print("." , end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```

I expect the output of "....." to be printed separately every second (during 5 seconds), but the actual output appeared altogether after 5 seconds.

Sorry for bad english but if you don't mind, please help me :)

Comment: Just change to this `print(".", end = " " )` , and remember to use python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time
for i in range(5):
    print('.', end=' ', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can I ask you more what  "flush=True" means?

Comment: [Print_funciton](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print) ,  [FlushOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function)

Answer (score 0):

So,

try to change your code to this:

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    print("." , end=" ", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

And look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3249539/11578778

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Best regards, Brhaka

Comment: The problem is solved with your code and adding "flush=True". Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome dude!