# how do i use a while loop to print numbers on the same line of output?

Tags: python-3.x

`n = 10
while n > 0:
    print(n)
    n=n-1`

so far i have this which gives me

10 
9 
8 
 7 
 6 
 5 
 4
3
2
1

but I want 
 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'end' parameter of print. By default, end="\n" in print, a newline character

```
n = 10
while n > 0:
    print(n, end=" ")
    n=n-1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do that.

Firstly, and probably the simplest, you can use the `end` argument of [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

For instance, you could do something like this:

```
n = 10
while n > 0:
    print(n, end=" ") # note the 'end' argument
    n=n-1
```

Which gives : `10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1` (with a trailing space and without carriage return).

Another way I can think of, but involves a bit more complexity in my opinion, is using [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Example:

```
print(" ".join(str(i) for i in range(10, 0, -1)))
```

Which gives : `10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1` (with a carriage return and without trailing space).