# How can I print the last line of code on a seperate line?

Tags: python, printing, line

I'm trying to print out the last line of code on a separate line, as it always prints on the same line as the spinner?

I've already tried removing the sleep function.

```
from halo import Halo
import time
from colorama import Fore

name = input("TARGET:\n")

spinner = Halo(text='\nCalling: ' + name, spinner='dots')

spinner.start('\rCalling: ' + name)

time.sleep(5)

print(Fore.GREEN + 'Call Successful! [Internet = POSITIVE]')
```

I expect the output of the last line to be on a separate line when printed.

Comment: Does stopping the spinner first work? Or possibly adding \n at the start of your print.

Comment: I just had to stop the spinner, thank you!  Also, I know this is a separate question, but how would can I clear an output in the terminal after it's been printed?

Comment: So that I can clear the target input and output above, and only have the final message in the console after the spinner stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options for you. On my system (Mac) your code doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to, it just prints loads of lines rather than a spinner. In any case here are options that I would expect to work:

### Stop the spinner

```
name = input("TARGET:\n")

spinner = Halo(text='\nCalling: ' + name, spinner='dots')

spinner.start('\rCalling: ' + name)

time.sleep(5)

spinner.stop()

print(Fore.GREEN + 'Call Successful! [Internet = POSITIVE]')
```

### Add a newline

```
name = input("TARGET:\n")

spinner = Halo(text='\nCalling: ' + name, spinner='dots')

spinner.start('\rCalling: ' + name)

time.sleep(5)

print("\n" + Fore.GREEN + 'Call Successful! [Internet = POSITIVE]')
```

Comment: Both options solved my problem, thank you!  Can you answer my other comment about clearing the terminal after an output?

Comment: Answer here hopefully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically

Comment: Would there be a way to simply clear the terminal after the spinner ends and print the last line, having it alone as the first line in the terminal?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/517970/11432434

Comment: Thank you so much!  Sorry about the easy fixes, I'm new to coding with python.  Very helpful! :)

Comment: No worries, please mark the answer accepted if it helped you out. Enjoy Python, it's a great language