# Can I print and clear one line?

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to make a loading type screen and I have tried multiple things. It always prints on the next line.

```
#attempt 1
print("loading"),
print("."),
print(".."),
print("..."),
#attempt 2
import time
print("loading", end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print(".", end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("..", end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("...",)
```

I expect the output to be

Loading.
———————
Loading..
———————
Loading...
———————

But it gives me an error message saying that it does not expect the

> end=" "

Comment: And regarding clearing lines, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically).

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Can you post the error traceback

Comment: You are using Python 2 and forgot to use `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: `print("."),` is legal in Python 3, but for different reasons than in Python 2 (and just produces a tuple `(None,)` that is immediately discarded.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I have fixed the formatting