# Python Process Progress Indicator Prompt

Tags: python

I have a nexted for loop like below:

```
for N1 in range(1, 96):
    for N2 in range(N1 + 1, 97):
        for N3 in range(N2 + 1, 98):
            for N4 in range(N3 + 1, 99):
                for N5 in range(N4 + 1, 100):
                    remaining coding logic
```

I would like to have a process progress indicator prompt (stationary line) to show the nexted for loops increment like

```
print("N1:", N1, "N2:", N2...)
```

All my attempts (like the print above or `sys.stdout.write/sys.stdout.flush`) have created scrolling process progress indicator prompt, what does not look really pretty.

Thank you

---

I have tried [progress](https://github.com/verigak/progress/), but doesn't work very well in the nested loop:

```
bar1 = Bar('Processing B1', max=20)
for i in range(20):
    bar2 = Bar('Processing B2', max=20)
    for x in range(20):
        bar2.next()
    bar2.finish()
    bar1.next()
bar1.finish()
```

```
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B2 |################################| 20/20
Processing B1 |################################| 20/20
```

Comment: Have you looked into [progress](https://github.com/verigak/progress/), [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm), or similar modules?

Comment: pass `end=''` to `print`

Comment: Do you mean that you want all prints to be on the same line? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following print statement;

```
print("\033[1G\033[0KN1:", N1, "N2:", N2, end='')
```

The stuff at the beginning are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_output_sequences).

- `\033[1G` means "move the cursor to column 1".
- `\033[0K` means "clear to the end of the line".