# print a random number * n times (all different numbers)

Tags: python, random

so I want an output like this `5, 7, 23, 15, 6, 3`  all random in one line Matrix

I know I could do

```
from random import randrange
for i in range(5):
    print(f' {randrange(50)}')
```

the problem with this they will not be in one line.

so I tried this
`print(f' {randrange(100)}' * 5)` but the output show similar numbers
like this `27, 27, 27, 27, 27`

any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Comment: Voting to reopen since OP wants to join on **comma-space** (`', '`), not just space, without a trailing comma.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. This tells others that the issue is resolved and allows them to find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `end=" "` to the `print` statement. This will put a space between each number instead of a new line.

```py
from random import randrange
for i in range(5):
    print(f"{randrange(50)}", end=" ")
```

Comment: You can also ditch the f-string here. `print(randrange(50), end=" ")`