# How do I make my Print Statement print on only one line?

Tags: python, random, while-loop, printing

In this program I am trying to print my code as "**random letters here**" instead of "r" "a" "n" "d" "o" "m" etc.

```
import random
import time

All = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
i = 0

while i < 6:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(All[random.randint(1,35)])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Comment: why the `time.sleep`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused why an intentional delay is there, but to answer your question you can include a `end=''` in the print statement to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `end=''` to the `print` statement so that subsequent `print`s are not separated by a newline, which is the default behavior. Also, here it makes sense to use a `range` iterator with `for` instead of `while`.

> **Note:** I've taken the liberty to cut the sleep time in half, so it's easier to test it out.

```py
import random
import time

All = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"

for _ in range(6):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(All[random.randint(1, 35)], end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

> ```
> import random
> import time
>
> All = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
> i = 0
> s = ""
> while i < 6:
>     time.sleep(1)
>     s += All[random.randint(1,35)]
>     i += 1
>
> print(s)
> ```

Every print statements ends with a newline, so you need to "build" you string first (s in this case) first, then print it once.

Comment: I think the idea of that `sleep` is to print in the same line but every second, not printing the entire result on one line

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import random
import time
import sys

All = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
i = 0
someString = ""
while i < 6:
    time.sleep(1)
    print()
    sys.stdout.write("\r "+str(All[random.randint(1,35)]))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this is a homework project/question but if it isn't I guess you could just jumble them up using `random.sample` *(I will un-iclude the* `sleep` *as there seems to be no need for it nor did you explain it's reasoning)*:

```
from random import sample

s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
print(*sample(s, k=len(s)), sep='')
```

Sample result:

```
urftloqb38swz1ma9x5yg4p2ceijdhnk07v6
```

Also just fyi, the string you are using can be made pragmatically using the string library:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

It does have the `0` before the `1` instead of at the end but considering what you're doing it shouldn't make any meaningful difference.