# How do I delete/replace a line in python?

Tags: python, replit

```
def walking():
Variable = True
while Variable == True: 
    print("Walking", end = "\r")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Walking.", end = "\r")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Walking..", end = "\r")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Walking...", end = "\r")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("          ", end = "\r")
```

Im trying to get it to print out an animation that goes:

Walking
delete it
Walking.
delete it
Walking..
delete it
Walking...
then repeat

I don't want to delete everything on the console since other things are going to be shown when this is shown

Comment: If thats all you're doing it would be far easier just to print one extra dot on the same line

Comment: or add `flush=True` to the print command ... read it up.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to do that, im still new to python

Comment: also:   `while True: ............ break`

Comment: `print("Walking", end = "", flush=True)` sleep `print(".", end = "", flush=True)` sleep `print(".", end = "", flush=True)` sleep `print(".", end = "", flush=True)` sleep `print(".", end = "", flush=True)`  ... no line deletion needed .. at the end overwrite with flush as well ... like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3249539/7505395) proposes