# How to print an output in the same line

Tags: python, fibonacci

I want to print the numbers in the same line to Fibonacci numbers.

Here is my code:

```
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
a = 0
b = 1
sum = 1
count = 1
print("Fibonacci numbers= ")
while(count < n):
    print(sum, end = " ")
    count += 1
    a = b
    b = sum
    sum = a + b
```

The output of this will be:
Enter n: 10
Fibonacci numbers=

> 

1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 >

How do I put it like this:
Enter n: 10

Fibonacci numbers= 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55

Thanks.

Comment: You do it the exact same way you did when you printed the numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

##### Solution

python `print` function would automatically append and new line sign "\n". To change that, just customize the `end` argument of the `print` function.

So, you just need

```py
print("Fibonacci numbers= ", end="")
```

---

##### demo with comments.

```py
n = int(input("Enter n: "))  # you input introduces an new line
a = 0
b = 1
sum = 1
count = 1
print("Fibonacci numbers=", end="")  # without new line
while(count < n):
    print(" {}".format(sum), end="") # without new line, use " " instead
    count += 1
    a = b
    b = sum
    sum = a + b
print("")  # only print a new line.
```

- Output:

  ```
  Enter n: 6
  Fibonacci numbers= 1  2  3  5  8
  ```