# designing of python command line apps

Tags: python, shell, cmd, wget

I am designing application which is a similar to wget and i am stuck between how to implement progress bar that flushes every time the screen to show current status of the file download.

I have uses "cls or clear " command by calling os.system but it doesnot works interactive way like wget can anybody suggest me how to do possible

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860680/python-overwrite-previous-line

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent progress bar script at http://nadiana.com/animated-terminal-progress-bar-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you have tried already but if you haven't seen this tutorial then check it out:
http://www.5dollarwhitebox.org/drupal/node/65

It was helpful to me.

Update: there is apparently even a library for this(I have not used it though). http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/