# Overwrite console output in python IDE

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder

I looked up how to overwrite the `print` output and found multiple questions concerning this issue. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860680/python-overwrite-previous-line). However, none of the mentioned solutions worked for me and I always get a new line. Is it because I use the Spyder IDE? Any ideas what I could do? I am using Python 2.7.12 with Spyder on Ubuntu 16.04. LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the **IPython** console in Spyder for this to work. The examples you posted work fine for me in that console, but not in the **Python** one, where they fail miserably.

Comment: Works for me :) . Still it would be interesting to know why it fails in the Python console...

Comment: We (I'm a Spyder developer) haven't added support to overwrite output in the Python console. Besides, that console is going to be removed in Spyder 4.0 because we don't plan to maintain it anymore.