# Keying either individual letters or an entire word into hangman game

Tags: python, if-statement, random, input, jupyter-notebook

I am currently creating a hangman game for a project. I have managed to code where a user can enter individual letters to guess the secret word. However, I am having trouble adding an additional feature where the user can guess the entire word upfront.

below is my code attempt, may I know what to write to have this new feature in my game?

```
def game_play():
    word = random.choice(WORDS)

    # Dashes for each letter in each word
    current_guess = "-" * len(word)

    # Wrong Guess Counter
    wrong_guesses = 0

    # Used letters Tracker
    used_letters = []

    while wrong_guesses < MAX_WRONG and current_guess != word:
        print (HANGMAN[wrong_guesses])
        print ("You have used the following letters: ", used_letters)
        print ("So far, the word is: ", current_guess)
    
        guess = input ("Enter your letter guess:")
        guess = guess.upper()
    
        # Check if letter was already used
        while guess in used_letters:
            print ("You have already guessed that letter", guess)
            guess = input ("Enter your letter guess: ")
            guess = guess.upper()

        # Add new guess letter to list
        used_letters.append(guess)

        # Check guess
        if guess in word:
            print ("You have guessed correctly!")
    
            # Update hidden word with mixed letters and dashes
            new_current_guess = ""
            for letter in range(len(word)):
                if guess == word[letter]:
                    new_current_guess += guess
                else:
                    new_current_guess += current_guess[letter]
                
            current_guess = new_current_guess
        else:
            print ("Sorry that was incorrect")
            # Increase the number of incorrect by 1
            wrong_guesses += 1
        
    # End the game
    if wrong_guesses == MAX_WRONG:
        print (HANGMAN[wrong_guesses])
        print ("You have been hanged!")
        print ("The correct word is", word)
    
    else:
        print ("You have won!!")

game_play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than prompting the user for a new guess each time, you could overwrite the line where you output their previous guesses so far, so the output may look something like:

```
Word: _ A N _ _ A N   Misses: B C D
```

This would mean they could just keep typing guess and the line would update. See [python overwrite previous line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860680/python-overwrite-previous-line) for details on how to overwrite previous line.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have certain restrictions on my project so I will have to ask for the user's guess each time...

Answer (score 0):

The input command will let you enter multiple letters. I don't see anything stopping the user entering the full word there already?

Instead of counting each letter which matches/fails you could maintain a set of correct/failed guesses and check against the number of items in the set. Maybe something like:

```
import random

WORDS = ['STACK', 'OVERFLOW', 'HELP']

def playgame():
    word = random.choice(WORDS)

    # valid characters
    valid = set((chr(c) for c in range(ord('A'), ord('A') + 26)))

    # unique characters in word
    unique = set((c for c in word))
    hits = set()
    misses = set()
    allowed_misses = 5

    complete = False
    while complete == False:
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ").upper()
        for c in (c for c in guess if c in valid):
            if c in unique:
                hits.add(c)
            else:
                misses.add(c)

            # break out of for
            if len(hits) == len(unique) or len(misses) > allowed_misses:
                complete = True
                break

        if not complete:
            # output continuation messages
            print(f'Hits: {hits} misses: {misses}')

    if len(hits) == len(unique):
        # output sucess message
        print(f'Success: hits {hits} misses {misses}')
    else:
        # output fail message
        print(f'Fail: hits {hits} misses {misses}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    playgame()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have included the additional feature to enter the entire word, and also refactored your code. If the user entered the entire word correctly, I'd assign `current_guess` with the correct word and break the while loop.  Please have a look

```
import random

WORDS = ['apple', 'kiwi', 'banana']
MAX_WRONG = 3

def game_play():
    word = random.choice(WORDS).upper()
    current_guess = '-' * len(word)    #hidden answer
    wrong_guesses = 0
    used_letters = []

    while wrong_guesses < MAX_WRONG and current_guess != word:
        print ('\nRemaining tries:', MAX_WRONG - wrong_guesses)
        print ('So far, the secret word is: ', current_guess)
        print ('You have used the following letters: ', used_letters)
        guess = input('Enter your letter guess:').upper()
        if guess == word:
            current_guess = word
            break    #exit the while-loop
    
        while guess in used_letters:    #check for duplicate input
            print ('You have guessed "' + guess + '" already!')
            guess = input ('Enter your letter guess: ').upper()
        
        used_letters.append(guess)    #append guess to used_letters
        if guess in word:
            print ('You have guessed correctly!')
            new_current_guess = ''
            for idx in range(len(word)):    #update hidden answer
                if guess == word[idx]:
                    new_current_guess += guess
                else:
                    new_current_guess += current_guess[idx]
            current_guess = new_current_guess
        else:
            print ('Sorry that was incorrect')
            wrong_guesses += 1
        
    if wrong_guesses == MAX_WRONG:
        print ('\nYou have been hanged!')
        print ('The correct word is', word)
    elif current_guess == word:
        print ('\nYou have won!! The word is:', word)

game_play()
```

Output:

```
Remaining tries: 3
So far, the secret word is:  ----
You have used the following letters:  []
Enter your letter guess: i
You have guessed correctly!

Remaining tries: 3
So far, the secret word is:  -I-I
You have used the following letters:  ['I']
Enter your letter guess: kiwi

You have won!! The word is: KIWI
```

Comment: this is a fun game! @luc_1101 did you manage to get it working?