# iPython Notebook Print Above Last Line

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a notebook that is going to print off hundreds of lines. Is there anyway to have the next line print above the last one?

As in:

```
Output_n    
...
Output 2
Output 1
```

Instead of:

```
Output1
Output2
...
Output_n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of! `from IPython.display import clear_output`, then calling `clear_output()` will clear everything. Then you reprint everything starting from Output_n. It's... not ideal.

[Here's a link.](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/3607712653c66d63e0d7f13f073bde8c0f209ba8/docs/examples/notebooks/Animations_and_Progress.ipynb)

Comment: That's kind of unfortunate. Your answer was correct, but wouldn't work in my case. I'm looking to have each character on the printed line appear to be typed slowly- like http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/visualize?nrow=5&ncol=5&pn=p1 The closest I've gotten is to just reset the line like- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465348/how-can-i-print-over-the-current-line-in-a-command-line-application

Comment: I mean, you can output javascript directly, so that's definitely doable.

Comment: Yeah, but that requires me to know javascript... Do you know of any good examples that can be used as a tutorial of sort to make what I'm looking for?